Error: Command '['/opt/homebrew/bin/ninja']' returned non-zero exit status 1
I upgraded my mac to the damn sonoma and it missed up several things for me. I am trying to run a python script that used to be working fine, but now I get the following error
"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/homebrew/bin/ninja']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

This seems to be related to ninja. I tried reinstall it and updating it but still facing the same problem.
The error include the command "/opt/homebrew/bin/ninja", when I run it in the command line I get
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory

Any help is greatly appreciated!

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

I thonk last error is not so important - when you run ninja without parameters then it may search file build.ninja to see what to do. But it means it works. You may also run it as ninja --help. More important is first error. You have to check rest of your first error - to see where in your code it makes problem. Maybe it use some path to file which doesn't exists or it was moved to different folder.
